# Implementing SSO in sharepoint 2013 with SAP

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, sso

I am looking for a solution that will connect SAP from SharePoint. What is best way to create SSO in SharePoint 2013 to SAP.
I am completely unaware of this type of requirement. Any one could explain in plain way and steps to implement my requirement.

**Requirement**

1. Create a SSO in Sharepoint 2013 with SAP
2. Create a Login in Sharepoint 2013
3. How to take care of SAP users in Sharepoint 2013
4. How can i maintain the user authorization for all applications.

Comment: Please be specific in terms of what SAP product that you are planning to integrate with SharePoint. such as SAP Business Objects, Crystal Reports and so on..